# How cleanup user data from Cloud Firestore after a user sign out

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How I can to cleanup user data from **Cloud Firestore** after a user **sign out**

I want to remove everything related to the user (collections, sub-collections, and images) a user sign out.

I use frigger a function **on user deletion** in **Cloud Function**

```
exports.cleanupUserData = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
    return ...
});
```

Are there any alternatives to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no Cloud Functions triggers for when a user signs in or out.  There are currently just triggers for when a user account is created or deleted.  With Firebase Authentication, users are expected to be able to sign in and out repeatedly without disruption to their data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can clone your user in **Firebase Authentication** to **Realtime Database** or **Firestore** and use the data in it. After that, to deal with your question is make a logic in **SignOut function** to **clear all data** in **Realtime Database** or **Firestore** based on your choice.